# Code first Migrations with IdentityUser gives an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use Code First Migrations with IdentityUser. 
Here's my dbContext

```
public class JbDb : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public JbDb()
            : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JbDb"].ConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public IDbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        public virtual IDbSet<T> DbSet<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    internal class Initialiser : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<JbDb>
    {
        protected override void Seed(JbDb context)
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for User model

```
[Table("User", Schema = "Security")]
public class User:IdentityUser
{
    public string UserId
    {
        get { return Id; } 
    }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

Connection String is like this:

```
 <add name="JbDb" connectionString="Data Source=CENLP\HRMSQL;Initial Catalog=JbDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but when i'm trying to enable the migrations, it gives an error saying

> > Checking if the context targets an existing database... System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple object sets per type are
> >     not supported. The object sets 'User' and 'Users' can both contain
> >     instances of type 'Jb.Model.Security.User'.    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.RegisterSets(DbModelBuilder
> >     modelBuilder)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
> >     internalContext)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
> >
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps()
> >     at System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists()    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.IsIdentityV1Schema(DbContext
> >     db)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String
> >     nameOrConnectionString, Boolean throwIfV1Schema)    at
> >     Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1..ctor(String
> >     nameOrConnectionString)    at Jb.DataAccess.JbDb..ctor() in
> >     d:\CENT-Jb\Jb\Jb.DataAccess\JbDb.cs:line 10
> >     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> >     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
> >     contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
> >     DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
> >     configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
> >     existenceState)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
> >     configuration)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
> >     migrationsConfiguration)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
> >     at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
> >     callBackDelegate)    at
> >     System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
> >     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
> >     runner)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String
> >     language, String rootNamespace)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
> >     command) Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object
> >     sets 'User' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
> >     'Jb.Model.Security.User'..

It will be really helpful if one can point me out what is wrong here

Comment: try remove         public virtual IDbSet<T> DbSet<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: thanks for the quick response. But i'm still having the same issue. Can u please figure out any other reason that could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Table("**Users**", Schema = "Security")]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. but after modifying to public  public JbDb()
            : base("JbDb")
        {
        } and removing all other code in that class, it worked fine